# R data.table add column as function of another data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have one data table which contains just a sequence of times. I have another data table containing two columns: start_time and end_time. I want to take the first data table and add a column where the value is the count of all of the rows in the second data table where the time from the first data table fits within the start and end time. Here is my code

```
start_date <- as.POSIXct(x = "2017-01-31 17:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
end_date <- as.POSIXct(x = "2017-02-01 09:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

all_dates <- as.data.table(seq(start_date, end_date, "min"))

colnames(all_dates) <- c("Bin")

start_times <- sample(seq(start_date,end_date,"min"), 100)
offsets <- sample(seq(60,7200,60), 100)
end_times <- start_times + offsets
input_data <- data.table(start_times, end_times)
```

Here is what i want to do, but this is wrong and gives an error. What's the right way to write this?

```
all_dates[, BinCount := input_data[start_times < Bin & end_times > Bin, .N] ]
```

In the end i should get something like

```
Bin                   BinCount
2017-01-31 17:00:00   1
2017-01-31 17:01:00   5
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `data.table` you're after a range join.

```
library(data.table)

start_date <- as.POSIXct(x = "2017-01-31 17:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
end_date <- as.POSIXct(x = "2017-02-01 09:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

all_dates <- as.data.table(seq(start_date, end_date, "min"))

colnames(all_dates) <- c("Bin")

set.seed(123)
start_times <- sample(seq(start_date,end_date,"min"), 100)
offsets <- sample(seq(60,7200,60), 100)
end_times <- start_times + offsets
input_data <- data.table(start_times, end_times)

## doing the range-join and calculating the number of items per bin in one chained step
input_data[
    all_dates
    , on = .(start_times < Bin, end_times > Bin)
    , nomatch = 0
    , allow.cartesian = T
][, .N, by = start_times]

#             start_times N
# 1:  2017-01-31 17:01:00 1
# 2:  2017-01-31 17:02:00 1
# 3:  2017-01-31 17:03:00 1
# 4:  2017-01-31 17:04:00 1
# 5:  2017-01-31 17:05:00 1
# ---                      
# 956: 2017-02-01 08:56:00 6
# 957: 2017-02-01 08:57:00 4
# 958: 2017-02-01 08:58:00 4
# 959: 2017-02-01 08:59:00 5
# 960: 2017-02-01 09:00:00 5
```

Note:

- I've put the `all_dates` object on the right-hand-side of the join, so the result contains the names of the `input_data` columns, even though they are your Bins (see [this issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1700) for the discussion on this topic)
- I've used `set.seed()`, as you're taking samples

Comment: Very clean solution. You were quick:) I had started on `data.table` based solution after feedback from OP.

Comment: Thanks - I've used this approach a lot. It's very similar to your SQL method, but written as data.table

Comment: True. Syntax are similar and then its depends on personal choice. I think it would be better to check performance in both way. IMO, `sqldf` will be equally fast if underlying `data.table` is indexed.

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be solved very easily using `sqldf` as it provides easy way to join tables with range checking. Hence one solution could be:

```
The data from OP:
library(data.table)
start_date <- as.POSIXct(x = "2017-01-31 17:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
end_date <- as.POSIXct(x = "2017-02-01 09:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

all_dates <- as.data.table(seq(start_date, end_date, "min"))

colnames(all_dates) <- c("Bin")

start_times <- sample(seq(start_date,end_date,"min"), 100)
offsets <- sample(seq(60,7200,60), 100)
end_times <- start_times + offsets
input_data <- data.table(start_times, end_times)


library(sqldf)

result <- sqldf("SELECT all_dates.bin, count() as BinCount 
                FROM all_dates, input_data
                 WHERE all_dates.bin > input_data.start_times AND 
                 all_dates.bin < input_data.end_times
                 GROUP BY bin" )

result
                    Bin BinCount
1   2017-01-31 17:01:00        1
2   2017-01-31 17:02:00        1
3   2017-01-31 17:03:00        1
4   2017-01-31 17:04:00        1
5   2017-01-31 17:05:00        1
6   2017-01-31 17:06:00        1
...........
...........
497 2017-02-01 01:17:00        6
498 2017-02-01 01:18:00        5
499 2017-02-01 01:19:00        5
500 2017-02-01 01:20:00        4
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 460 rows ]
```

Comment: Thanks - i also solved it using a for loop (but it's ugly) .. i'm hoping there's a nice way to do this directly in data table syntax

Comment: The similar syntax will be needed in `data.table` as well. Obviously for-loop will be very slow but performance of `sqldf` and `data.table` will be comparable.

Comment: A small shortening of the SQL statement could be obtained by using `between`.

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't requested, but here is a compact alternative solution using the `tidyverse`. Uses `lubridate` parsers, `interval`, and `%within%`, as well as `purrr::map_int` to generate the desired bin counts.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
start_date <- ymd_hms(x = "2017-01-31 17:00:00") # lubridate parsers
end_date <- ymd_hms(x = "2017-02-01 09:00:00")

all_dates <- tibble(seq(start_date, end_date, "min")) # tibble swap for data.table

colnames(all_dates) <- c("Bin")

start_times <- sample(seq(start_date,end_date,"min"), 100)
offsets <- sample(seq(60,7200,60), 100)
end_times <- start_times + offsets
input_data <- tibble(
  start_times,
  end_times,
  intvl = interval(start_times, end_times) # Add interval column
  )

all_dates %>% # Checks date in Bin and counts intervals it lies within
  mutate(BinCount = map_int(.$Bin, ~ sum(. %within% input_data$intvl)))
# A tibble: 961 x 2
   Bin                 BinCount
   <dttm>                 <int>
 1 2017-01-31 17:00:00        0
 2 2017-01-31 17:01:00        0
 3 2017-01-31 17:02:00        0
 4 2017-01-31 17:03:00        0
 5 2017-01-31 17:04:00        0
 6 2017-01-31 17:05:00        0
 7 2017-01-31 17:06:00        0
 8 2017-01-31 17:07:00        1
 9 2017-01-31 17:08:00        1
10 2017-01-31 17:09:00        1
# ... with 951 more rows
```

Comment: Always good to see alternative ways of doing the same thing, thanks!